# PHP Facebook Login With Mysql

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm trying to make a website with a facebook login button, I tried using php sdk and I have a problem: when I login the session isn't saved so it doesn't find it so it acts like it's not set.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    //Application Configurations
    $app_id     = "MY_API_KEY_HERE";
    $app_secret = "MY_SECRET_KEY_HERE";
    $site_url   = "http://localhost/";

    try{
        include_once "src/facebook.php";
    }catch(Exception $e){
        error_log($e);
    }
    // Create our application instance
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     => $app_id,
        'secret'    => $app_secret,
        ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    // We may or may not have this data based 
    // on whether the user is logged in.
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
    // the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
    //print_r($user);
    if($user){
        // Get logout URL
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    }else{
        // Get login URL
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope'         => 'read_stream, publish_stream, email, user_about_me',
            'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
            ));
    }

    if($user){

        try{
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        //Connecting to the database. You would need to make the required changes in the common.php file
        //In the common.php file you would need to add your Hostname, username, password and database name!
        mysqlc();

        $name = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['name'], "text");
        $email = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['email'], "text");
        $gender = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['gender'], "text");
        $bio = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['bio'], "text");
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM newmember WHERE email = %s",$email);
        $res = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
        if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)
        {
            $iquery = sprintf("INSERT INTO newmember values('',%s,%s,%s,%s,'yes')",$name,$email,$gender,$bio);
            $ires = mysql_query($iquery) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user_profile['email'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user_profile['id'];
        }
        else
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user_profile['id'];
        }
        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                error_log($e);
                $user = NULL;
            }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: no session_start() in the beginning

Comment: doesnt work , even if i put it , it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

To Facebook Integration and Login, [PHP Facebook Login And Integration in PHP](https://www.studytutorial.in/php-facebook-login-and-integration-in-php-website-tutorial), It explained in details and download Facebook SDK from here.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

$appId = 'YOUR APP ID'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = 'YOUR APP SECRET KEY'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL = 'YOUR CALLBACK URL'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions = array('email');  //Optional permissions

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
        ));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Try to get access token
try {
    // Already login
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        } else {
            // Put short-lived access token in session
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

            // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
            $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

            // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
            $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

            // Set default access token to be used in script
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        }

        // Redirect the user back to the same page if url has "code" parameter in query string
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

            // Getting user facebook profile info
            try {
                $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture');
                $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();
                // Here you can redirect to your Home Page.
                echo "<pre/>";
                print_r($fbUserProfile);
            } catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                session_destroy();
                // Redirect user back to app login page
                header("Location: ./");
                exit;
            } catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Get login url

        $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);
        header("Location: " . $loginURL);

    }
} catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
?>
```